# Julia Kernel Error in Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda)

Tags: anaconda, julia, jupyter

When I open a Julia 0.6.0 notebook using Jupyter, the kernel tries to connect, fails and the a red button "Kernel Error" appears at the top right of the notebook. I uninstalled and reinstalled, but nothing has changed. The following is the message I got when I click on the "Kernel error":

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you do not have enough permissions to start the Julia Kernel. 
You should not need to be administrator to use the Julia kernel, but it seem like your computer is believing you should.

Try running the julia interpreter, and kernel manually to see if you can.

Comment: It does work manually and I can open the notebook from the REPL. But the same error reappears when I open a Julia notebook directly from Jupyter. When I run `Pkg.checkout("IJulia")` from the REPL, The following is the output: `Checkout IJulia master` `Error: IJulia is dirty, bailing`.

Comment: You need to flush the julia packages; I don't know where they are on windows; but it uses git internally; if the files have been tampered with git bails out and give you this error message.